# Do I need a feed network when used two port (coax probe) for Circular polarization?

Tags: antenna

I used two coax probe to feed my patch antenna on CST; they're perpendicular to each other. There's no connection between the probes. For axial ratio, two broadband simulations I got, one 'farfield broadband [1]' and other is 'farfield broadband [2]'.  Their gains are same. (So sounds circular to me). However, Axial ratio vs freq plot is same with when the only one port used and simulated. Highly suspected that CST only considers the one port, not both.  In such a case, do we usually need a feed network? Or any way possible to browse both monitors since it only browse 'farfield broadband [1]' or 'farfield broadband [2]' at once.

Hope that explained well. Appreciated in advance for any kind of help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically want the antenna to only act as one specific circular polarization? Indeed, CST likely only uses one port as default.
I am not familiar with CST myself, but in HFSS and EMPro you can select which ports you want driven and what their phase relationship and amplitude ratios are. This way you could make a circular polarization by driving one port with 90 degrees phase shift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Joren! I can adjust port phases and amplitudes and actually I did. However, while plotting Axial Ratio vs Freq in CST, farfield result template only allows me to select i.e 'farfield (broadband) [1[1.0,0.0]]' OR 'farfield (broadband) [2(1.0,90)]'. As you know, if I wanna get the plot of axial ratio vs freq of the antenna, It needs to use of those both, right? or Do I need to select only one port for excitation and dechecked the other one while simulating?